# Google Apps Script function getActiveSheet() does not return active sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[The Google Apps Script Developers' Guide's definition of an "active sheet"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSheet()):

> The active sheet in a spreadsheet is the sheet that is being displayed in the spreadsheet UI.

[image: my sheets]

If I have three sheets, named Mary, Moe, and Joe, and leave the Mary sheet on display (hence, it's the active sheet) and run this simple script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(sheet.getName());

  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2]);
  Logger.log(ss.getActiveSheet().getName());
}
```

I expect the output to say

```
[18-10-26 18:41:45:724 EDT] Mary
[18-10-26 18:41:45:730 EDT] Joe
```

But, in fact, it says:

```
[18-10-26 18:49:14:752 EDT] Moe
[18-10-26 18:49:14:755 EDT] Joe
```

And if I run it a second time without touching the sheets, I would expect the output to say

```
[18-10-26 18:50:51:930 EDT] Joe
[18-10-26 18:50:51:933 EDT] Joe
```

But it actually says the same thing as before

```
[18-10-26 18:50:51:930 EDT] Moe
[18-10-26 18:50:51:933 EDT] Joe
```

In other words, setting the active sheet does indeed change the sheet that's on display in the Spreadsheet UI, but it doesn't seem to internally register the new sheet as the active sheet. GAS is always recognizing Moe as the active sheet, even after setting the active sheet to a different one.

I would appreciate an explanation and a way to fix this problem. Basically, I simply need `getActiveSheet()` and `getActiveRange()` (which has similar issues) to give me the sheet that is currently visible in the Spreadsheet UI, exactly as defined in the Developer Guide.

Edit: I found a solution to this problem. I am quoting myself from the comments.

> Hi everyone, thank you all for your input. I just discovered that
>   getActiveSheet() does indeed work the way I was hoping it would, but
>   only if you run the function through a custom menu UI built using
>   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(...), which needs an onOpen()
>   trigger (thanks to @I'-'I for this tip). Running the function from the
>   script editor causes the problems that inspired my original post.

However, while I am glad I found a solution, it feels more like a workaround leaving the core problem unresolved. I feel as though `getActiveSheet()` should act as defined in the Developer Guide in both cases, in the Menu UI and the script editor. It doesn't make sense that it works in one and it doesn't in the other.

Comment: can you share the spreadsheet with ful access to try the coe please?

Comment: I actually created a copy because the sheet I used for my post contains confidential work-related information... should have thought ahead of that one. Anyway, this new sheet behaves in the same way, except I get Joe-Joe every time now, regardless of which sheet is on display
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BqUrsEji3NBBIm_Uli-zTG6Wzfvo5vfX5zduTQeBFOk/edit#gid=1369242463

Comment: thanks you very much

Comment: can you tell what web-browser you are using please. It works for me.

Comment: Hi JSmith, Thanks for the feedback. I'm using Mozilla Firefox 63.0 (Quantum) for 64-bit Windows 10 OS

Comment: Just updated Firefox to 63.0 like yours and still it works for me. @I'-'I do you have the same problem as Manuel?

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you all for your input. I just discovered that getActiveSheet() does indeed work the way I was hoping it would, but only if you run the function through a custom menu UI built using SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(...), which needs an onOpen() trigger (thanks to @I'-'I for this tip). Running the function from the script editor causes the problems that inspired my original post.

Answer (score 1):

**Display All Sheets for 10 seconds**

This script will cycle through all of the sheets in a spreadsheet activating them one at a time and displaying them for approximately 10 second.

```
function cycleThroughAllSheets() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shA=ss.getSheets();
  var start=new Date();
  for(var i=0;i<shA.length;i++){
    shA[i].activate();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    ss.toast('Active Sheet is ' + shA[i].getName());
    do{
      //nothing
    }while(new Date().valueOf()-start.valueOf()<10000);
    start=new Date();
  }
  ss.toast('End of Script.')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code. I tried it out myself and it works wonderfully. However, this isn't exactly what I was trying to do. I want to use the function getActiveSheet(), as opposed to cycling through the sheets, and I was disappointed to find that it doesn't work the way I expect it to under certain circumstances, unless I'm wrong about that in some way.

Comment: I think  your script would have worked if you would have used `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` everytime after the activate() method.